# giving id to the text field

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form at which 2 fields are generated by one drop down menu. Now the problem is I have generated one field and trying to get two fields, in first field price is shown and in second tag product_id is shown. My script is just showing price but not id. Due to lack of knowledge I am stuck. I just need help from someone.

JavaScript:

```
function setOptions(chosen) {
    var selbox = document.myform.opttwo;
    selbox.options.length = 0;
    if (chosen == " ") {
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please select one of the options above first',' ');   }
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('100 Directory Submission', '$9.99', '1');
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('200 Directory Submission', '$19.99', '2');
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('300 Directory Submission','$29.99', '3');
    }
    document.myform.amount.value="";
    document.myform.hidden.value="";
}​
```

HTML:

```
<select name="opttwo" size="1" onchange="this.form.amount.value=this.value;">
    <option value=" " selected="selected">Select any option of the above first</option>
</select>
Amount Payable:<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="amount" />
Product id:<input type="text" name="hidden" readonly="readonly" />
```

Comment: Your script has lot of error check     if (chosen == " ") {
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please select one of the options above first',' ');   **}**  you have to close it later

Comment: Also you're missing a form and as far as I can see you're not calling your setOptions(); from anywhere. I made a fiddle for you that you can use in your question: http://jsfiddle.net/wQMAK/

Comment: that errors are just accidently written. in my actual code there is nothing.

Comment: @limelights I saw your code but it is also not giving me product_id.

Comment: I updated the fiddle, i pasted in the wrong url. sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

<strike>First off there are some obvious problems with your code such as closed and unclosed braces.</strike>

One example of that is on this line:

```
if (chosen == " ") {
        selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('Please select one of the options above first',' ');   }
```

Edit: this is not no longer the case.

Secondly, the Options object that you're trying to create does not have the "id" property that you're trying to get unfortunately.

So your code

```
selbox.options[selbox.options.length] = new Option('100 Directory Submission', '$9.99', '1');
```

is not getting '1' as its id.

The constructor is

```
new Option([text], [value], [defaultSelected], [selected])
```

You can however get the index of an element by doing this in your onchange handler:

```
this.form.hidden.value=this.selectedIndex;
```

Thirdly, if you wanna continue on the path of using script in your onchange tags, which generally is discouraged, you have to set the value of the hidden input as well.

Like this:

```
onchange="this.form.amount.value=this.value; this.form.hidden.value=this.value;"
```

Note: this line above will give you the wrong value, just saying, but you get the gist of it.

I made a fiddle for you to toy around in and to see how it's done.

[Here is it](http://jsfiddle.net/wQMAK/4/)

Some API documentation is always in order I believe:

Update:
In order to set the id dynamically on every Option you have to loop over the elements in the select list like this:

```
for (var i=0; i<selbox.length; i++){
     selbox.options[i].setAttribute('id', 'hello'+i); 
}
```

Then in the line where you set in your `onchange()` you add this

```
this.form.hidden.value=this[selectedIndex].id;
```

Now your input should show, when you select an option, "hello0", "hello1", "hello2", "hello3".

Also, I updated the fiddle for you.

[Mozilla Option API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Option)

Comment: I've updated the fiddle to reflect my answer better! Sorry for the confusion that it might cause!

Comment: your work is remarkable but this is not what i am searching for. updated script just gives the index number which is selected. I don't want index number I need to print my desired number. Hope you understand it.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that but as your code is now you will not be able to do that. What you need to do is to assign each of the options an id  either programmatically or hardcoded. The API you're using does not support what you want.

Comment: then guid me how can I hardcode the id to each and every option which is in javascript? If I can not give id then I might choose different way to show similar results.